# RSA Encryption and Decryption on partial ciphertext?

Tags: math, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I've successfully built and compiled an application on my PC which will generate an RSA keypair (I used GPK for the long arithmetic). I then tested encryption/decryption on a string "Hello World" (ASCII --> Hex transform first).

The question I have is, is is mathematically possible to only decrypt "Hello" from my cipher-text string "Hello World", or would I have to encrypt "Hello" first, then encrypt "World", and then decrypt them separately?

EDIT: My desired use-case:

I have a chip (Zynq SoC from Xilinx), which only has 256K of on chip memory, and 512K of L2 cache.

I can prefill and lock the cache with some basic instructions/data, and then use the 256K for my stack, heap, and .data/.bss sections of code (variables).

I need more space, so I was thinking I could use the 256K as "swap" space, and fetch the rest of the .text (the instruction code) from the external, encrypted flash, but I need to decrypt it on-chip to maintain the security.

I was wondering if I could encrypt the entire image, then "fetch, decrypt, decode, execute". It looks like I might be restricted to encrypting my image in 256K chunks, and decrypting it in that size of chunks as well.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Don't use RSA for this. Use a block cipher, like AES - those support the kind of chunked operation you're thinking of, and at a much smaller chunk size (e.g, 128 or 256 bits at a time). I believe the Zynq SOC may even have AES in hardware already.

Answer (score 2):

RSA is a mathematical operation. You can't recover only part of the plain text; doing the math (*c<sup>d</sup> mod n*) will yield the entire plain text. As you suggest, you'd have to perform two separate RSA encryption operations if you want to decrypt two parts separately.

This sounds a bit like an X-Y problem. What are you really trying to accomplish?

---

*Update:* RSA is best used as a key encryption algorithm: instead of encrypting data directly, you encrypt the key for a symmetric algorithm with RSA, then encrypt your application data with that symmetric algorithm. This is the way RSA is used in protocols like TLS, S/MIME, PGP, and any other widely accepted protocol.

So, use an algorithm like AES (use a suitable mode, preferably one that provides integrity protection) together with RSA for a secure and efficient system.

Comment: added EDIT above. I am trying to have a secure application stored on an external Non volatile memory, but only have a subset-size of space available on my chip.

Comment: @IDLacrosseplayer Okay, I think I understand your application, but you need to change your approach.